# Fiddler - unable to save multiple hosts in filter

Tags: fiddler

I use filters a lot in Fiddler, to switch between filtering for multiple related sites. However, I'm having problems saving some of these filters.

As an example, if I go to the Filters tab, I can add a single domain like this:

```
*.example.com
```

and save it (using the Actions->Save Filterset... button) as example.ffx. In that file, there is a line as follows:

```
<slHosts>*.example.com;</slHosts>
```

I then change the filter to also try to include another set of domains which includes a trailing wildcard (e.g. example.co.uk, example.co.au):

```
*.example.com;*.example.co.*
```

This filters correctly at run-time, but when I try to save the new filterset (Actions->Save Filterset...), it won't save - it gives me the option to overwrite the existing example.ffx, but it doesn't save - the filters tab reverts to the original value with only *.example.com. This also happens if I save the new filterset under a different name.

This only seems to happen with trailing asterisks - the filters *work*, but they can't be *saved*. Even if I manually edit the .ffx file to include both domains like this:

```
<slHosts>*.example.com; *.example.co.*;</slHosts>
```

when I load the filterset file, it only includes the first domain in the Filters tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler's `HostList` object (used in the Filters tab and elsewhere) supports leading wildcards only; it does not support wildcards elsewhere in the string.

The Filters tab's UI *should* properly reflect the state (e.g. when you move away, it should delete the tail-wildcard rule); I'll pass this bug along to the development team.

Comment: Hey @EricLaw, it's a shame that it can't support non-leading wildcards. FWIW, if you specify a non-leading wildcard, it does appear to work currently (it just can't be saved) - are you suggesting that the Dev team may remove that functionality?

Comment: Non-leading wildcards don't work. The code has a different list for "Tail matches" and it's used if the first character is *.

Comment: So no way to have a filter of e.g. *.example.* then? I has a sad.

Comment: Not with the Filters tab, no (though if "example" is sufficiently obscure, you could use the Filter's tab's "Hide if URL Contains" rule.) You can trivially add a Host limit like this using FiddlerScript.

Comment: Ah - I meant that I wanted to only see requests which _include_ `*.example.*` - so all of example's various global websites...

Comment: Sure, and if `.example.` is unlikely to occur in a path or a query string, a "Hide if url contains" rule will work.